# jQuery plugin development execute a setting that is a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, jquery-plugins

I'm fiddling around trying to put together an autocomplete jQuery plugin. I know there's a default one, but I found that I sometimes just need something really simple and also would like to adjust behavior to my needs. Last it's kinda fun to expierence around. If it turns out into something useful I might put together a small plugin site for it.

Anyway; the plugin has some options. One of them is `dataSource`. It can be an object, string or function. I'm trying to accomplish the task to get the function executed. I've tried to `eval` it, but when I console.log it just logs the javascript code the function consists of.

Implementation of the plugin

```
$('#search3').myAutoCompletePlugin({
    completeOnEnter: false,
    delay: 200,
    dataSource: function() {
        console.log('Hello!');
    }
});
```

In the plugin's code, this is how I try to execute it.

```
...
getResults: function() {
    var self = this,
        dataSourceType = typeof self.options.dataSource;

    self.request.items = [];

    ...
    } else if (dataSourceType == 'function') {
        // Callback as source, execute it
        self.request.items = eval(self.options.dataSource);
        console.log('function executed');
        console.log(self.request.items);
    } 
    ...
},
...
```

I would expect it log "Hello!", but what I get is:

```
function executed
function () {
        console.log('Hello!');
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `dataSource` property is a function you can then just call it directly, there's no need for `eval()`:

```
else if (typeof self.options.dataSource == 'function') {
    self.request.items = self.options.dataSource();
    console.log('function executed');
    console.log(self.request.items);
}
```

Comment: Well, that was unbelievably easy. Stupid that I didn't think of that earlier. Thanks, works like a charm! +1A